# Dúvida sobre tamanho da array

Tags: c, array

Tenho uma dúvida referente a array, por exemplo, se eu tiver 2 arrays de tamanho 9 e for imprimir os valores de ambas é normal a entrada 9 pegar o valor 0 da próxima array ?, isso é mais um teste, sei que o máximo é 8 ?

Exemplo de código:

```
struct stType {
  type[9];
}select;

strcut vrType {
  type[9];
}variable;

void st_type(int type, int value) {
    int i;
    uint32 type_select = select_type(type);

    ST_TYPE(i, type_select) {
        select->type[i] += value;
    }
}

void vr_type(int type, int value) {
    int i;
    uint32 type_select = variable_type(type);

    VR_TYPE(i, type_select) {
        variable->type[i] += value;
    }
}

int main() {
    st_type(0, 50); // define valor 50 para array select->type[0]
    vr_type(0, 60); // define valor 60 para array variable->type[0]

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        printf("[ST Debug %d] Value: %d\n", i, select->type[i]);

        printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("[VR Debug %d] Value: %d\n", i, variable->type[i]);
}
```

Saída:

```
[ST Debug 0] Value: 50
[ST Debug 1] Value: 0
[ST Debug 2] Value: 0
[ST Debug 3] Value: 0
[ST Debug 4] Value: 0
[ST Debug 5] Value: 0
[ST Debug 6] Value: 0
[ST Debug 7] Value: 0
[ST Debug 8] Value: 0
[ST Debug 9] Value: 60 // posição 9 puxa o 0 de vr

[VR Debug 0] Value: 60
[VR Debug 1] Value: 0
[VR Debug 2] Value: 0
[VR Debug 3] Value: 0
[VR Debug 4] Value: 0
[VR Debug 5] Value: 0
[VR Debug 6] Value: 0
[VR Debug 7] Value: 0
[VR Debug 8] Value: 0
[VR Debug 9] Value: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim é perfeitamente normal. Isto acontece devido a forma como as variáveis são alocadas em c, mas também depende do compilador. Observe as seguintes situações:

```
int a = 5, b = 10;

int main() {
  int *p = &a;
  printf("%d\n", *p);
  p++;
  printf("%d\n", *p);
}
```

Se você compilar este código usando o [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc) ou mesmo o [vc++](/questions/tagged/vc%2b%2b), o programa ira produzir a seguinte saída:

```
5 - 10
```

Nesse caso temos duas variáveis globais e a memória foi alocada na ordem em que as variáveis foram declaradas, uma após a outra. O mesmo se passa no teu exemplo, primeiramente alocou-se a memória o primeiro vetor, e logo a seguir para o segundo, fazendo com que o último elemento do primeiro vetor fique mesmo ao lado do primeiro elemento do segundo vetor.

Mas nem sempre as coisas acontecem desse jeito. Observe o segundo exemplo:

```
int func(int a, int b){
   int *p = &a;
   printf("%d - ", *p);
   p++;
   printf("%d", *p);
}

int main() {
   func(5, 10);
}
```

Este código possui uma saída quando compilado com o [vc++](/questions/tagged/vc%2b%2b) e outra com [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc).

Saída VC++: `5 - 10`
Saída GCC:  `5 - 0`

Como se pode ver neste exemplo, em c não há uma regra que determine a ordem como as variáveis são alocadas. No teu exemplo  `select->type[9]` é igual a 60, mas talvez num outro compilador ou numa outra plataforma as coisas não seriam assim.

Comment: Entendo, eu estava achando que era problema no meu código por isso me surgiu essa dúvida, seu exemplo foi bem esclarecedor, obrigado.

Comment: @Carol na verdade é problema no seu código e esta resposta está induzindo a erro, por mais que haja boa intenção. Não é como C aloca variáveis e não depende do compilador. Note que os exemplo sequer tratam do seu problema. Ela até está correta no problema que está falando, mas não é o mesmo que o seu. A resposta dá a entender que seu código está certo. É o que eu falei, você está acessando uma área de memória que não foi designada para aquela variável, se você tem posições de 0 a 8, tentar acessar a 9 é possível, mas semanticamente errado produzindo um resultado certamente errado...

Comment: ...ainda que funcione por coincidência https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0Toi.png

Comment: @Maniero, em momento algum falei que o cógigo está certo, só quis mostrar porquê que as funcionaram desse jeito. O primeiro exemplo é sim o mesmo caso que o dela. O segundo foi só pra mostrar o quão imprevisível (e consequentemente perigoso) c pode se tornar quando se trata deste assunto. E você tem razão quando diz que é errado tentar acessar a memória que não foi designada para uma variável.

Answer (score 2):

Na verdade ter um zero é uma coincidência, poderia ter qualquer valor aí. Está pegando um valor que está em uma posição de memória fora da área reservada para este *array*. Você sabe que vai do 0 ao 8, então o 9 é algo que vem logo a seguir na memória.

C permite acessar toda a memória da aplicação sem restrições, é problema do programador garantir que não está acessando algo indevidamente.

Comment: Entendo, mais isso prejudica algo no código ?

Comment: Muito, você está acessando uma área que não deveria, o que tem lá é considerado lixo, e consumira isto. Pior, se mexer lá alterará algo que faz parte de outro objeto danificando-o.